# Add SQL filter based on Pandas Dataframe values

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I would like to add a condition in my SQL query that only extracts the `customer_id's`and the corresponding `city` that are in the `customer_id_df`

My code below currently extracts all `customer_id's` and is missing the condition mentioned above.

**customer_id_df**

```
customer_id
4244
2424
5353
5273
5353
6342
```

**Main_table**

```
customer_id  city
4244         Houston 
2424         Los Angeles
5353         Detroit 
5273         New York
5353         Detroit
6342         Austin 
1123         New York
3113         San Francisco 
9923         Boston
```

**output_df**

```
customer_id  city
4244         Houston 
2424         Los Angeles
5353         Detroit 
5273         New York
5353         Detroit
6342         Austin
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import jaydebeapi

customer_id_df = pd.read_csv('<file_path>')

conn = jaydebeapi.connect("<JDBC connection details>")
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select customer_id,city from main_table ") 
columns = [desc[0] for desc in curs.description]       # getting column headers
output_df = pd.DataFrame(curs.fetchall(), columns = columns)
```

Comment: yes left_join - but I would want to add the filter before running the query to avoid extracting all the customer_id's

Comment: try f'select customer_id,city from main_table where customer_id in [{*list(customer_id_df['customer_id'].values)}]' not sure it will work, if you don't mind filtering after fetching you could use pandas isin.

Comment: unfortunately does not work

Comment: try experimenting with hard coded list, if you find one that works, experiment on how to get it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

In order to get each value (with duplications) and merely join the two tables together on 'customer_id' as key (equivalent to INNER JOIN with SQL):

```
new_df = pd.merge(output_df, customer_id_df,how = 'inner' , on=['customer_id'])
```

In order to get merely distinct values (without duplications (equivalent to SELECT DISTINCT with SQL):

```
new_df.drop_duplicates(subset ="customer_id", 
                 keep = "first", inplace = True)
```

That would be it. Let me know if you need further help!